# Was ist die Bedeutung von "gleich" als Partikel?

Tags: particle

Was ist die Bedeutung von *gleich* in diesem Kontext:

> Lieber Helmut,
>
> ich muss dir gleich schreiben.

Comment: Was sind denn die allgemeinen Bedeutungen von "gleich" lt. Wörterbuch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Wort „gleich“ kann sehr viele verschiedene Bedeutungen haben. In *Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* findet man beispielsweise:

> **gleich**
>
> **I.** <Adj.>
>
> **1. a)** *in allen Merkmalen, in jeder Hinsicht übereinstimmend*
>
> **b)** *miteinander od. mit einem Vergleichsobjekt in bestimmten Merkmalen, in der Art, im Typ übereinstimmend; sich gleichend; vergleichbar*
>
> **2.** *unverändert, gleich bleibend*
>
> **3. *jmdm. g. sein** *jmdm. gleichgültig sein*; **etw. ins Gleiche bringen** *etw. in Ordnung bringen*; **von Gleich zu Gleich** *auf einer Ebene, Stufe*
>
> **II.** <Adv.>
>
> **1. a)** *in relativ kurzer Zeit, sofort, [sehr] bald*
>
> **b)** *unmittelbar daneben; dicht bei*
>
> **2.** *erstaunlicherweise auf einmal, zugleich*
>
> **III.** <Partikel>
>
> **a)** drückt in Fragesätzen aus, dass der Sprecher nach etwas eigentlich Bekanntem fragt, an das er sich im Moment nicht erinnert; *noch; doch*
>
> **b)** drückt in Aussage- u. Aufforderungssätzen Unmut od. Resignation aus
>
> **c)** *überhaupt*
>
> **IV.** *einem anderen Menschen, einer anderen Sache gleichend; wie*

Hier trifft der Fall II. 1. a) zu:

> ich komme gleich
>   es muss nicht gleich sein
>   gleich nach dem Essen gingen sie weg
>   warum nicht gleich so?
>   bis gleich!

Bei dem in der Frage genannten Satz ist das Wort „gleich“ ein Adverb, das das Verb „schreiben“ näher bestimmt:

> ich muss dir schreiben
>   ich muss dir gleich schreiben
>   ich muss dir sofort schreiben

Grundsätzlich wäre auch denkbar:

> ich muss dir bald schreiben
>   ich muss dir in kurzer Zeit schreiben

Da aber der Verfasser mit ebendiesen Worten den Brief bereits jetzt schreibt, hätte ein solcher Ausblick in die Zukunft hier sicherlich keinen Sinn.

Comment: Im süddeutschen Raum sowie im deutschsprachigen Teil der Schweiz kann "gleich" auch die Bedeutung "trotzdem" haben.